# JKS file location in KTor

Tags: kotlin, yaml, ktor

After creating a JKS file for KTor ssl communication and configuring the following:

```
ktor:
  deployment:
    port: 8100
    sslPort: 8181
  application:
    modules:
      - com.mainmodule
  development: true
  security:
    ssl:
      keystore: main_debug.jks
      keyAlias: main
      keyStorePassword: mainpassword
      privateKeyPassword: mainpassword
```

I can't figure out where do I have to place my `main_debug.jks` file? In another toy project I have just placed it under `build` directory but that should be a temporary one. If I place it there it might be delete at some later time, isn't it?

There is no information in the official documentation where to place it so I'm stuck.

Comment: You need to place it in the current working directory (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory). In the IntelliJ IDEA, it can be configured in the edit run configuration form.

Comment: So you're saying I can't put it somewhere within my project directory tree? I'd expect it to be automatically deployed. And why do I need to specify it in the **Run Configuration** if I have it in my `application.yaml`?

Comment: In the end I found a solution that I like. I also had to swap `yaml` to `HOCON`. For an unknown reason `yaml` configuration does not work, even if it is basically the same as `HOCON`. I am surprised that trivialities like these aren't specified anywhere in the Ktor documentation. I am already thinking of dropping Ktor as Back-End solution but I will post my own answer soon enough anyway. Maybe it will be useful to someone.